# OpenCV frame rate when reading video different than what used for capture

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am using OpenCV to capture videos with a number of different cameras (OpenCV 4.5.1.48 on Ubuntu 18.04). For all the cameras I set the capturing frame rate to 30fps, but I noticed when reading the fps of the recorded video through

```
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_path)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps)
```

that the values are never exactly 30 fps, but rather

```
30.00030000300003
30.000299988570422
29.997772583098968
...
```

and so on. Is this behaviour expected? When I right click on the videos and look at the video properties, it always says 30 fps.
The videos I am recording are around 10 minutes, but if I cut a smaller section of the video (e.g. 30 seconds) than the departure from 30 fps is even greater and OpenCV would read even 29 fps instead of 30.

Would there be any real downsize from rounding the detected frame rate to an integer when processing the video? In the specific I am looking to record an output video at 10 fps taking one every three frames of the original video, so I'm wondering if setting the frame rate of the video writer to 10 fps is correct or if I should be using one third of the fps read by OpenCV.